# My Weather app with current, hourly and daily forecasts

Tags: beginner, react.js, jsx

This is my first independent project. Do you have any criticisms or suggestions before I deploy it?

[image: large viewport app]

[image: small viewport app]

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import CurrentWeather from './components/CurrentWeather';
import { getCities, getWeather } from './api';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';

import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import DailyForecast from './components/DailyForecast';

import { getBackground } from './background';
import { weatherCodes } from './weathercodes';

import clearDay from './assets/clearDay.jpg';

function App() {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);

    const { status, data: weather } = useQuery({
        enabled: selectedValue !== null,
        queryKey: ['weather', selectedValue],
        queryFn: () => getWeather(selectedValue),

        onError: (error) => console.log(error),
    });

    const currTime = new Date(Date.parse(weather?.current_weather.time));
    const sunRise = new Date(Date.parse(weather?.daily.sunrise[0]));
    const sunSet = new Date(Date.parse(weather?.daily.sunset[0]));
    const isDaytime =
        currTime.getHours() > sunRise.getHours() &&
        currTime.getHours() < sunSet.getHours()
            ? true
            : false;

    const handleSelectionChange = (value) => {
        setSelectedValue(value);
    };

    const loadOptions = (searchValue) => {
        return getCities(searchValue);
    };

    return (
        <div className="grid overflow-x-hidden min-h-screen">
            <img
                src={
                    weather
                        ? getBackground(
                                isDaytime,
                                weatherCodes[weather.current_weather.weathercode]
                          )
                        : clearDay
                }
                style={{
                    position: 'fixed',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    objectFit: 'cover',
                    zIndex: '-1',
                }}
                alt="Weather Background"
            ></img>

            <div className="flex flex-col items-center h-full gap-5 lg:gap-0">
                <div className="flex flex-row w-full mt-3 lg:ml-5 justify-center lg:justify-start">
                    <div className="lg:w-1/5 lg:mr-3 w-1/2">
                        <AsyncSelect
                            placeholder="Search for city"
                            styles={{
                                control: (baseStyles) => ({
                                    ...baseStyles,
                                    borderRadius: '25px',
                                    width: '100%',
                                }),
                            }}
                            cacheOptions
                            defaultOptions
                            value={selectedValue}
                            getOptionLabel={(e) =>
                                `${e.name}, ${e.admin1}, ${e.country_code}`
                            }
                            getOptionValue={(e) => ({
                                longitude: e.longitude,
                                latitude: e.latitude,
                            })}
                            loadOptions={loadOptions}
                            onChange={handleSelectionChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                {status === 'loading' ? (
                    <div className="flex h-full items-center justify-center text-center mx-5">
                        <span className="text-5xl text-white">
                            Welcome to my weather app! Search for your city to get real time
                            weather now!
                        </span>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-center lg:gap-5 lg:mt-2">
                        <CurrentWeather
                            city={selectedValue?.name}
                            locale={selectedValue?.admin1}
                            currentWeather={weather.current_weather}
                            hourly={weather.hourly}
                            HiLow={[
                                weather.daily.temperature_2m_max[0],
                                weather.daily.temperature_2m_min[0],
                            ]}
                            isDaytime={isDaytime}
                            sunRise={sunRise}
                            sunSet={sunSet}
                        />

                        <DailyForecast dailyWeather={weather.daily} />
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const searchClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://geocoding-api.open-meteo.com/v1/search',
});

const weatherClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast',
});

export function getCities(searchValue) {
    return searchClient
        .get(`?name=${searchValue}&language=English`)
        .then((res) =>
            res.data.results.filter(function (value, index, self) {
                if (
                    index ===
                        self.findIndex(
                            (i) =>
                                i.name === value.name &&
                                i.admin1 === value.admin1 &&
                                i.country_code === value.country_code
                        ) &&
                    value.admin1
                ) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            })
        )

        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}

export function getWeather(selectedValue) {
    return weatherClient
        .get(
            `?latitude=${selectedValue.latitude}&longitude=${selectedValue.longitude}&current_weather=true&hourly=temperature_2m,weathercode&temperature_unit=fahrenheit&timezone=auto&daily=temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,sunrise,sunset,weathercode`
        )
        .then((res) => res.data)
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

**CurrentWeather.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import TempCard from './TempCard';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import HourlyForecast from './HourlyForecast';

import { weatherCodes } from '../weathercodes';

dayjs().format();

function CurrentWeather({
    city,
    locale,
    currentWeather,
    hourly,
    HiLow,
    isDaytime,
    sunRise,
    sunSet,
}) {
    const currTime = new Date(Date.parse(currentWeather.time));
    const currHour = currTime.getHours();
    const dateString = dayjs(currTime).format('MMMM DD, YYYY');

    const timeArr = hourly.time.slice(currHour, currHour + 24);
    const tempArr = hourly.temperature_2m.slice(currHour, currHour + 24);
    const weatherCodeArr = hourly.weathercode.slice(currHour, currHour + 24);

    const hourlyWeather = timeArr.map(function (time, index) {
        let hour = new Date(Date.parse(time));

        return [hour, tempArr[index], weatherCodeArr[index]];
    });

    return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 lg:auto-cols-min w-[80%] lg:gap-5 ">
            <TempCard
                currentTemp={currentWeather.temperature}
                city={city}
                locale={locale}
                date={dateString}
                description={weatherCodes[currentWeather.weathercode]}
                HiLow={HiLow}
                isDaytime={isDaytime}
                dateString={dateString}
            />

            <HourlyForecast
                hourlyWeather={hourlyWeather}
                currTime={currTime}
                sunSet={sunSet}
                sunRise={sunRise}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default CurrentWeather;
```

**TempCard.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import WeatherIcon from './WeatherIcon';

function TempCard({
    currentTemp,
    city,
    locale,
    dateString,
    description,
    HiLow,
    isDaytime,
}) {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-row justify-start col-span-2 space-x-20 ">
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center text-white text-shadow-lg h-">
                <span className="mt-2 p-1 text-center text-4xl 3xl:text-6xl  ">
                    {city}, {locale}
                </span>
                <span className="text-xl 3xl:text-3xl">{dateString}</span>
                <div className="w-[70%] h-full ">
                    <WeatherIcon description={description} isDaytime={isDaytime} />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col rounded-xl items-center justify-center gap-4 text-white text-shadow-lg">
                <span className=" text-9xl 3xl:text-11xl text-center w-full ">
                    {Math.round(currentTemp)}&deg;
                </span>
                <span className="text-4xl 3xl:text-6xl w-full text-center">
                    {description}
                </span>
                <span className="text-3xl 3xl:text-5xl text-center w-full">
                    {Math.round(HiLow[0])}&deg; | {Math.round(HiLow[1])}&deg;
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TempCard;
```

**HourlyForecast.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import HourlyCard from './HourlyCard';
function HourlyForecast({ hourlyWeather, currTime, sunSet, sunRise }) {
    return (
        <div className="col-span-2 flex flex-row lg:ml-2 lg:gap-2 ">
            <div className="lg:flex lg:items-center lg:justify-center lg:col-start-6 lg:col-end-6 lg:w-1/4 hidden">
                <div className="h-[200px] 3xl:h-[300px] lg:bg-white w-[1px]"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row overflow-x-scroll scrollbar-hide items-center justify-start gap-4">
                {hourlyWeather.map((weather) => {
                    let hour = weather[0];
                    let hourString = hour.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric' });
                    return (
                        <HourlyCard
                            key={weather}
                            hour={
                                currTime.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric' }) ===
                                hourString
                                    ? 'Now'
                                    : hourString
                            }
                            temperature={Math.round(weather[1])}
                            weatherCode={weather[2]}
                            isDaytime={
                                hour.getHours() > sunRise.getHours() &&
                                hour.getHours() < sunSet.getHours()
                                    ? true
                                    : false
                            }
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default HourlyForecast;
```

**HourlyCard.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import WeatherIcon from './WeatherIcon';
import { weatherCodes } from '../weathercodes';

function HourlyCard({ hour, temperature, weatherCode, isDaytime }) {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col shrink-0 rounded-xl items-center text-2xl 3xl:text-4xl text-white bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-40 w-[13%] lg:w-1/5">
            <span className="w-full text-center ">{hour}</span>
            <div className="w-full">
                <WeatherIcon
                    description={weatherCodes[weatherCode]}
                    isDaytime={isDaytime}
                />
            </div>

            <span className="w-full text-center">{temperature}&deg; </span>
        </div>
    );
}

export default HourlyCard;
```

**DailyForecast.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import DailyCard from './DailyCard';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

dayjs().format();

function DailyForecast({ dailyWeather }) {
    const weekdays = [
        'Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday',
    ];
    const dailyCards = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        let day = weekdays[new Date(dailyWeather.time[i]).getUTCDay()];

        // let day = dailyWeather.time[i];
        dailyCards.push(
            <DailyCard
                key={i}
                day={day}
                weatherCode={dailyWeather.weathercode[i]}
                high={dailyWeather.temperature_2m_max[i]}
                low={dailyWeather.temperature_2m_min[i]}
            />
        );
    }
    return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 grid-rows-7  w-[80%]  mb-4 mt-3 lg:gap-4">
            {dailyCards}
        </div>
    );
}

export default DailyForecast;
```

**DailyCard.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { weatherCodes } from '../weathercodes';
import WeatherIcon from './WeatherIcon';

function DailyCard({ day, weatherCode, high, low }) {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-row 3xl:h-2/3 items-center text-white text-2xl 3xl:text-4xl mt-1 mb-1 rounded-xl bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-40 space-x-10">
            <span className="w-full text-center ">{day}</span>
            <div className="w-1/6 h-full">
                <WeatherIcon description={weatherCodes[weatherCode]} isDaytime={true} />
            </div>
            <span className="w-full text-center">
                {Math.round(high)}&deg; | {Math.round(low)}&deg;
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DailyCard;
```

**weathercodes.js**

```
export const weatherCodes = {
    0: 'Clear Sky',
    1: 'Mostly Clear',
    2: 'Partly Cloudy',
    3: 'Cloudy',
    45: 'Fog',
    48: 'Fog',
    51: 'Drizzle',
    53: 'Drizzle',
    55: 'Drizzle',
    56: 'Drizzle',
    57: 'Drizzle',
    61: 'Slight Rain',
    63: 'Moderate Rain',
    65: 'Heavy Rain',
    66: 'Light Rain',
    67: 'Heavy Rain',
    71: 'Light Snow',
    73: 'Moderate Snow',
    75: 'Heavy Snow',
    77: 'Snowing',
    80: 'Light Showers',
    81: 'Moderate Showers',
    82: 'Heavy Showers',
    85: 'Light Snow Showers',
    86: 'Heavy Snow Showers',
};
```

**background.js**

```
import clearDay from './assets/clearDay.jpg';
import clearNight from './assets/clearNight.jpg';
import cloudyDay from './assets/cloudyDay.jpg';
import cloudyNight from './assets/cloudyNight.jpg';
import cloudy from './assets/cloudy.jpg';
import fogDay from './assets/fogDay.jpg';
import fogNight from './assets/fogNight.jpg';
import rainyDay from './assets/rainyDay.jpg';
import rainyNight from './assets/rainyNight.jpg';
import snowyDay from './assets/snowyDay.jpg';
import snowyNight from './assets/snowyNight.jpg';

export function getBackground(isDaytime, description) {
    let bgImg = null;
    if (isDaytime) {
        switch (description) {
            case 'Clear Sky':
                bgImg = clearDay;
                break;

            case 'Mostly Clear':
            case 'Partly Cloudy':
                bgImg = cloudyDay;
                break;

            case 'Cloudy':
                bgImg = cloudy;
                break;

            case 'Fog':
                bgImg = fogDay;
                break;

            case 'Drizzle':
            case 'Slight Rain':
            case 'Moderate Rain':
            case 'Light Rain':
            case 'Light Showers':
            case 'Moderate Showers':
            case 'Heavy Rain':
            case 'Heavy Showers':
                bgImg = rainyDay;
                break;

            case 'Light snow':
            case 'Light Snow Showers':
            case 'Snowing':
            case 'Heavy Snow':
            case 'Heavy Snow Showers':
                bgImg = snowyDay;
                break;

            default:
                bgImg = clearDay;
                break;
        }
    } else {
        switch (description) {
            case 'Clear Sky':
                bgImg = clearNight;
                break;

            case 'Mostly Clear':
            case 'Partly Cloudy':
                bgImg = cloudyNight;
                break;

            case 'Cloudy':
                bgImg = cloudy;
                break;

            case 'Fog':
                bgImg = fogNight;
                break;

            case 'Drizzle':
            case 'Slight Rain':
            case 'Moderate Rain':
            case 'Light Rain':
            case 'Light Showers':
            case 'Moderate Showers':
            case 'Heavy Rain':
            case 'Heavy Showers':
                bgImg = rainyNight;
                break;

            case 'Light snow':
            case 'Light Snow Showers':
            case 'Snowing':
            case 'Heavy Snow':
            case 'Heavy Snow Showers':
                bgImg = snowyNight;
                break;

            default:
                bgImg = clearNight;
                break;
        }
    }

    return bgImg;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/283206/revisions#rev-body-1de531ae-5966-4fb2-bc35-ade61aaab847) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: @Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ thank you, it's definitely much better this way